# Authorizing the BlueJeans API with a Django app

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, bluejeans

I'm trying to make a Django app automatically send invites to BlueJeans video conferences using its API (https://bluejeans.github.io/api-rest-meetings/site/index.html). However, I'm finding it not so straightforward to set this up, and their customer support staff seem to not all be completely familiar with these features either.

When you request to enable API access in BlueJeans, the customer support enables an "OAuth Access" tab with a form which allows you to create an app with a name, description, and 'app key':

[image]

My question is: what should I fill in for the "app key"? (I've browsed the [OAuth 2.0 RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) but so far haven't been able to apply it to solve this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From BlueJeans' API documentation (which is shared as a PDF to developers who enable the API for their enterprise account), you can simply 'make up' an 'App Key' on the spot, and BlueJeans will create a corresponding 'App Secret'.

[image]